# Client Server Facebook Registration / log in flow

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have a problem implementing a Facebook Login on my ASP.NET website. I have both [.NET Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk) and the Javascript SDK installed in my site. I can't understand the **flow** that I need to implement in order to make it work.

In my app, I just need the email to register the user, give him the option to choose a username, and be able to login if he clicks the Facebook log in button (a custom one, it's not the official Facebook log in button).

I prefer a seamless login in which I get login the user via Ajax request to the server and set a cookie on the server instead of a redirect.

What is the registration and login flow that I need to implement to make it work using Ajax?

What I tried to do is to get the token on the client, but when I get the Token, I can't use it on the server, I need a code in order to get an active Token.

On my site I have both a custom Facebook signup and Facebook login buttons.

In my database I have the following columns for Facebook:

- facebook_id
- token
- token_expiration

Here's the client code that I get the accessToken, userId and use it to get the user email:

```
 function fb_login() {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {               
            access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                user_email = response.email; //get user email
            });

        } else {
            //user hit cancel button
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {
        scope: 'email'
    });
}
```

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: @Seano666 In the FB.login return function, I check if response.authResponse is true and get the access_token and user_id. I'll update the question with the code.